# Firebase Analytics not showing user engagement for iOS app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, fabric.io

I have an iOS app that uses Firebase Analytics, which was working very well. I was able to see user engagement and, particularly, I used a lot the "latest release" screen on the Firebase console. Also crashlytics was working well.

Two weeks ago, I built a release of the app and sent it to the AppStore. The release version was 4.10.3, however due to marketing reasons we decided to release it as 5.0.0. I kept the same build number (4.10.3) and just changed the version number on AppStoreConnect (5.0.0).

As soon as this version was available on the appstore, Firebase stopped showing ANY analytics information for this app. I can't see the daily active users, and can't see latest version adoption.

I thought this might be a bug on Firebase because of the difference between the app bundle version (which was 4.10.3) and the appstore version (which was 5.0.0). On Fabric all the analytics and crashlytics information are shown perfectly.

At some point, I found out that the "latest version" Firebase console screen stopped showing information even for the Android version of the app. Now I can only see "No data to display." on the console screen.

This is really weird because I was accessing the firebase console almost daily, until it stopped working for iOS a couple of weeks ago. Did some major change happen on Firebase recently?

On the Android app we upgraded the Firebase sdk version, but it still is not showing latest release info. On the iOS i've upgraded the Firebase pods as well, and am still waiting for the version to be reviewed on the appstore, however I'm not optimistic because even with the current version the app is working on fabric and is not working on the firebase console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few updates on the Firebase SDK and sending new versions of my app to the AppStore, Firebase Analytics started working again.

Comment: Hey! I just ran up to this problem on a web page (and not sure if it works yet) but, after you updated were you able to see old analytics like before or just data from where you updated?